# Populate cases based off Case ID instead of Reference ID?

Tags: salesforce-id, email2case

Is there a way to populate cases based off CaseID instead of ReferenceID? So if a customer sends in an email without the Reference ID, but it still has the Case ID, it updates the correct case, rather than creating a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with an Email Service. Please refer to Bryan Gilbert's post here as a reference: http://sforcehacks.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/email-to-case-can-create-too-many-cases.html